# How to follow moved div on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have struckture like this:

```
<div id="stuff">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

The divs will be dynamically added, meaning I cant say how much there will be.

When I rearrange the divs with jquery, is there a way to acces one of them even after they are moved?
Is there some dynamically way to add an id to them and/or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: will it be always added at the end?

Comment: what did you want to access, and how would you like to access it ( clicking the div or selecting from dropdownlist or other method )

Comment: you can assign an Id when you are adding the div (some sort of counter id).. how are you adding the div. can you show more code.

Comment: Yes, it will always be added at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a code snippet!

http://jsfiddle.net/q4273/

html:

```
<input class="btn teach_edit_header_buttons" style="font-family:Helvetica" type="submit" value="Add Div">
<div id='parent'></div>
```

js:

```
$(function () {

    $("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
        // get the available children
        var len = $('#parent').children('div').length;

        //determine the id = length+1
        var id = "item" + (len + 1);

        // append the child
        $("<div id='" + id + "'/>").html(id).appendTo("#parent");
   })

});
```

Comment: thats great.
When i wanted to delete a div I guess I would declare len before $("input[type=submit]").click(... and icrement it by one each time I add a new div?! Otherwise I could get two divs with the same id.

Comment: That should work! but btw, you did not mention that "divs can be deleted" in your question :-)

Answer (score 3):

Give id to each div based on its **sequence position** like below:

```
<div>
  <div id='pos1'>1</div>
  <div id='pos2'>2</div>
  <div id='pos3'>3</div>
</div>
```

Then you can easily follow it using its position class **irrespective its changed position**.

alternatively you can use classes but they behaves slowly.

Comment: be careful doing this. class names dont like starting with numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/648350

Comment: @haxxxton -  Thanks for flashing light on class names. corrected my answer.

Comment: no probs :) similarly, this would be a great option for using `id` rather than `class` given we want them to be unique :)

Comment: @haxxxton - edited answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: How would I achieve this? With some kind of loop?

Comment: And why would you use a class and not an id? I heard that using an id is sligtly faster.

Comment: @Ant1koerper - Yeah you'll require a loop.

Comment: @Ant1koerper -  You are right ids are faster. reedited my answer to have that.

Answer (score 0):

You must give and id to your div when you dynamically creat them. Maybe with JQuery :

```
.attr("id","myid");
```

Comment: Can you write a little more code?
I would use 'myid' with a number at the end i guess?!